# Select Max and Min into a same column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm doing an exercise and I'm having problems with the output.
My output:

```
ABC 3 PQRS 4 //this Output is wrong
```

and the Output that I should be able to produce:

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4 //this should be my Output
```

This is my query:

```
select min(name) ,len(min(name)), max(name), len(max(name)) from customers
```

How could I return both? `min(name)` with `len(min(name))` and  `max(name)` with `len(max(name))` in two columns???
With my query I'm returning the results but clearly in four columns and I need to return it in two columns as I showed above in the example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT MIN(name) AS name, LEN(MIN(name)) AS length
FROM customers
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(name) AS name, LEN(MAX(name)) AS length
FROM customers
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Subquery and Ranks. Logic is pretty straight forward. Ranking the length ASC and Desc, Then collecting first of each. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT 
        name,
        lenname
    FROM  (
            SELECT 
                name,
                len(name) lenname,
                RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(name),name) as ranksasc,
                RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(name) DESC,name) as ranksdesc
            FROM STATION
            GROUP BY 
                name
                ) OPR
    WHERE ranksasc = 1 OR ranksdesc = 1
    ORDER BY 
        name;
```